# SQL command not properly ended... dont know if I'm missing parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
-- joining 3 tables...
SELECT 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.PRACT_ID,
    PRACTITIONER.LAST_NAME, 
    PRACTITIONER.FIRST_NAME, 
    PRACTITIONER.MIDDLE_INITIAL, 
    PRACTITIONER.DEGREE, 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.FACCODE, 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.PRIMARY_FACILITY, 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.STATUS_CATEGORY, 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.SECTION_NAME, 
    PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS.DOCUMENTNAME, 
    PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS.ID_NUMBER, 
    PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS.EXPIRATION_DATE
FROM 
    PRACTITIONER 
INNER JOIN 
    PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS ON (practitioner_id_numbers.pract_id = practitioner.pract_id)
WHERE 
    practitioner_id_numbers.documentname LIKE "radio*" 
    OR practitioner_id_numbers.documentname LIKE "flouro*"
    AND PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS.HISTORICAL = FALSE 
INNER JOIN 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES ON (PRACTITIONER.PRACT_ID = PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.PRACT_ID)
WHERE 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.CURRENT_STATUS="Current"
ORDER BY 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.SECTION_NAME;
```

Comment: Change first `where` to `on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple `WHERE` clauses in your query -- you are only allowed one.

You must chain all your source tables (`FROM` and `JOIN` clauses) first, then apply a single `WHERE` clause, followed by an `ORDER` clause.

It also looks like you have some `AND` / `OR` precedence issues; I adjusted these to what appears to be what you intend, but you will want to look closely to make sure this is correct.

---

```
SELECT PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.PRACT_ID,
    PRACTITIONER.LAST_NAME, 
    PRACTITIONER.FIRST_NAME, 
    PRACTITIONER.MIDDLE_INITIAL, 
    PRACTITIONER.DEGREE, 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.FACCODE, 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.PRIMARY_FACILITY, 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.STATUS_CATEGORY, 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.SECTION_NAME, 
    PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS.DOCUMENTNAME, 
    PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS.ID_NUMBER, 
    PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS.EXPIRATION_DATE
FROM PRACTITIONER 
    INNER JOIN PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS ON (practitioner_id_numbers.pract_id = practitioner.pract_id)
    INNER JOIN PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES ON (PRACTITIONER.PRACT_ID = PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.PRACT_ID)
WHERE PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.CURRENT_STATUS="Current"
    AND (practitioner_id_numbers.documentname LIKE "radio*" OR practitioner_id_numbers.documentname LIKE "flouro*")
    AND PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS.HISTORICAL = FALSE 
ORDER BY PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.SECTION_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things don't look right with that SQL.

- Sql does not allow double quote ("), instead use single quote (').
- Also FALSE is nothing, you have to use 0 for a bit data type.
- Inner joins have to come before all the where clauses

I don't have your tables but his query parses correctly

```
SELECT  PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.PRACT_ID,
    PRACTITIONER.LAST_NAME, 
    PRACTITIONER.FIRST_NAME, 
    PRACTITIONER.MIDDLE_INITIAL, 
    PRACTITIONER.DEGREE, 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.FACCODE, 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.PRIMARY_FACILITY, 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.STATUS_CATEGORY, 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
    PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.SECTION_NAME, 
    PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS.DOCUMENTNAME, 
    PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS.ID_NUMBER, 
    PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS.EXPIRATION_DATE
FROM    PRACTITIONER 
    INNER JOIN PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS ON (practitioner_id_numbers.pract_id =  practitioner.pract_id)
    INNER JOIN PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES ON (PRACTITIONER.PRACT_ID = PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.PRACT_ID)
WHERE   practitioner_id_numbers.documentname like 'radio*' or practitioner_id_numbers.documentname like 'flouro*'
    AND PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS.HISTORICAL = 0 
    AND PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.CURRENT_STATUS= 'Current'
ORDER BY PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.SECTION_NAME;
```

Comment: Thanks...but it seems like it does not retrieve anything.... the syntax is right tho!!

Comment: I have updated the code and it now works.